# Lock underflow/overflow with Java LocalTime

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time, localtime

When subtracting a given amount from a LocalTime object, I've realised that overflow/underflow can occur.

Example:

```
00:30 - 35 minutes = 23:55
23:30 + 35 minutes = 00:05
```

For my application, I would like lock times such that the above would generate `00:00` on underflow, and `23:59` on overflow.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Try writing the code, and ask us if you have a concrete problem, posting the code you wrote.

Comment: can show us an example about `overflow`

Comment: @JBNizet I'll post the solution I'm using, but I was just curious what solutions existed.

Comment: @Pshemo Yep. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is:

```
    LocalTime orig = LocalTime.of(0, 30);
    int minutesToSubtract = 35;
    long minutesSinceMidnight = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalTime.MIN, orig);
    LocalTime result;
    if (minutesToSubtract > minutesSinceMidnight) {
        // Subtracting the minutes will pass midnight at start of day
        result = LocalTime.MIN;
    } else {
        // Normal case, no underflow
        result = orig.minusMinutes(minutesToSubtract);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

The above assumes that `minutesToSubtract` is non-negative. If negative numbers may occur, you need to check for both underflow and overflow.

The case of checking for overflow (more than `23:59:59.999999999`) is similar. Use `LocalTime.MAX` for end of day.

**Edit:** JB Nizet’s code for the other operation in his comment deserves proper code formatting, so I am pasting it here:

```
public static LocalTime addWithoutOverflow(LocalTime baseTime, int minutes) {
    LocalTime maxTime = LocalTime.MAX;
    long maxNanos = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(baseTime, maxTime);
    long nanos = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes).toNanos();
    return baseTime.plusNanos(Math.min(maxNanos, nanos));
}
```

Comment: I would use the same idea. Here's my implementation for the other operation: `public static LocalTime addWithoutOverflow(LocalTime baseTime, int minutes) {
        LocalTime maxTime = LocalTime.MAX;
        long maxNanos = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(baseTime, maxTime);
        long nanos = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes).toNanos();
        return baseTime.plusNanos(Math.min(maxNanos, nanos));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In this example, a route should be locked x amount of time before it starts.

```
1 |LocalTime firstStopTime = firstStop.getStopTime(); 
2 |LocalTime earliestTime = firstStopTime.minus(beforeRouteLockTimeMins % 1440, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
3 |LocalTime latestTime = firstStopTime.plus(afterRouteTimeLockMins % 1440, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
4 |
5 |// Handle underflow/overflow when getting earliest/latest time
6 |if (earliestTime.isAfter(firstStopTime)) earliestTime = LocalTime.MIN;
7 |if (latestTime.isBefore(firstStopTime)) latestTime = LocalTime.MAX;
```

On line 2 and 3, I am using % to avoid the lock time being greater than 24 hours. This way regardless of overflow/underflow, it can't pass the original time, so the checks on lines 6 and 7 will work.

I then assume that if the subtraction for earliest time is actually later than the stop, then it must have underflowed, therefore set it to 00:00, and the reverse for the latest time.

Finally, the times can be compared like so:

```
// Check route is within time constraint
if (currentTime.isBefore(earliestTime)) {
    return new RouteAvailabilityResponseModel(false, "Too early to begin route.");
} else if (currentTime.isAfter(latestTime)) {
    return new RouteAvailabilityResponseModel(false, "Too late to begin route.");
} else {
    return new RouteAvailabilityResponseModel(true, "Route can be started.");
}
```

Whilst this solution is working for me right now, I would like to see if there are any other less verbose options. (Then again this is Java.)